# How do I use cv::remap with forward mesh, not reverse mesh, to warp images?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I have a mesh of, say, 11 x 11 vertexes. The idea is that every point(vertex) holds the normalized floating-point position of that pixel in the warped image. E.g. if I want to stretch the upper left edge, I write in the first vertex (-0.1, -0.1).

I have the grid, but not the image warping function. [cv::remap](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html#cv-remap) does exactly that ... but in the reverse order - the mesh "says" which pixel neighborhoods to map to a regular grid on the output.

Is there a standard way in OpenCV to handle reverse warping? Can I easily transform the mesh or use another function? I am using OpenCV and Boost, but any free library/tool that does that will work for me.

PS: I need this running on a linux PC.

Comment: I solved my problem. The issue was real urgent, so I poked people around in the office, until a solution was found (a proprietary one, alas).

However, I am still very puzzled why such a problem (image warping through a forward-grid) has not been solved in an open, free and accessible manner.

Comment: Could you please give some details how did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Marcin, unfortunately the EGL guy wrote a reverse mapper for the device in maybe a week (that's what I meant by 'proprietary solution'). It still puzzles me why such functionality is not included in OpenCV. Maybe someday someone shall solve the problem and post a reference to the pull request here as an answer. Maybe me, hmmmmm, or you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate another maps for the reverse transform.

But, for that you need the transform formula, or matrix.

**Step 1:** Select 4 points on the remapped image. A good idea would be to take the corners, if the corners are not black (undefined)

**Step 2:** Find their place in the original image(look into the maps for that)

**Step 3:** Compute the homography between the two sets of points. `findHomoraphy()` is the key.

**Step 4:** warpPerspective the second image. Internally, it calculates the grids, then calls remap();

If you have the same transform as earlier, invert input points with output points in findHomography, or inv() the resulting matrix.

If you want to have the maps for multiple calls (it's faster than calling warpPerspective each time), you have to copy the code from warpPerspective in a new function.

Comment: Hi, vasile and thanks for the answer. I think it is not what I am looking for, as it cuts down degrees of freedom. I shall explain - the mesh is arbitrary and there is no constraint straight lines in the original image to be projected into straight lines in the result.

Comment: Hmmm, my solution works only for transforms that are described by a geometrical relationship - a 3D transform. If your mesh describes a fish-eye lens distortion, or something like that, the only solution is to write a function that takes the input mesh and creates the output one as an inverse function.

Comment: Yeah, even more general - the mesh nodes positions are quite arbitrary. Turns out an alternative function to the one in Opencv, but that accepts forward-mapped warp is "easily" implemented in OpenGL - "only" about a week's work. Another proposed solution was to write such a function that you mention  - some bilinear interpolation on the (non-rectangular) output grid, to find the corresponding input grid coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at http://code.google.com/p/imgwarp-opencv/. This library seems to be exactly what you need: image warping based on a sparse grid.